# How can I set up default Makefile flags for all my Linux kernel compilations?

Tags: linux, makefile, compilation, kernel

Is there a way that I can set my kernel Makefile flags to always include "-j9"?  I often forget to type that flag manually when I recompile a new kernel that I've newly downloaded and configured and so the compile takes longer than it should on my machine.  My strategy for updating a kernel is:

1. Download a new kernel and put it in `/usr/src/linux-new`
2. `cp /usr/src/linux-old/.config /usr/src/linux-new`
3. `make oldconfig`
4. `make all modules_install`

I'd really like a CONFIG variable or something like that so that this method would automatically transfer the old Makefile flags over to the new directory and then I wouldn't have to remember to pass that pesky -j9 flag myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about putting steps 3 and 4 (or maybe 2, 3, and 4) into a shell script or alias, and executing that instead?

```
#!/bin/bash
make -j9 oldconfig
make -j9 all modules_install
```

Name this makeit or something easy to remember.

```
makeit
```

Comment: I might add that the -j9 is more useful for the second make command than the first and that the script shouldn't be called as ./ since it won't be part of the standard linux kernel download and should instead be part of the root's PATH